# How do I solve this with recursion?

Tags: java, math, recursion

I'm trying to do some simple math in java but I'm having some issues getting it to work. I want to take a number and increase it once per day, with the increase being a percent of the starting number at the beginning of each day and then adding it onto the starting number of the next day.

As in, if the starting number was 5 and the daily increase was 50%, then the number should be 5 for the first day, 7.5 for the second day, then 11.25, etc...

I already figured out how to do this iteratively, but I can't seem to get it to work recursively

here's a rather sloppy failed attempt:

```
   increase = start * percent;
   endNum = start + increase;
   startingNum += increase;
   return endNum;
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this recursively?

Comment: Why don't you use quartz scheduler creating a job putting this increment logic.

Comment: What's the exit condition ?

Comment: It exits once the program reaches the number of days its specified to run. I have that set up and running in a different method

Comment: @Anil it looks like a class exercise, no need to use Quartz here =\

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 parameters in your recursive function:

- The starting number.
- The percentage to increase on each *iteration*.
- The number of times (counter) you will increase the starting number. This is the parameter you currently lack in your recursive formula.

So, having this third parameter, the only thing you should do is call your function recursively until the counter goes down to 0.

Algorithm sample:

```
function doFooOperation (start, percent, counter)
    if (counter == 0) return 0
    //do your operations here...
    return doFooOperation(start, percent, counter - 1)
end function
```

Comment: Note that I don't post a full working code, instead just showing a sample of how your code should look. Giving you the whole answer would be cheating.